# How do you set the outbound ip address of sendmail?

Tags: email-server, centos7, sendmail

How do you set the outbound ip address of sendmail?

There are dozens of tutorials but most just tell you what to set without explaining anything and most of them assume you're running a virtual machine and only have a static ip.

Setup
The server is a physical machine running centos 7 with port 25 opened on the LAN and in SElinux with the option to send emails from apache enabled. I keep getting timeout errors when I attempt to send outbound emails. I've tested on gmail, yahoo and godaddy emails.

When I tested with `nmap --traceroute` and cURL I see that my outbound connections are going over the dynamic ip address which has port 25 blocked by the isp.

I need to still connect from the LAN because ssh and most other ports are closed to the outside world. Port 25, 80, 443 and a couple others are open to the outside world. All but port 25 seem to be properly handled by their associated applications.

Output of `ip show`

```
$ ip route show
default via 192.168.1.254 dev enp4s0f0 proto static metric 100
default via 108.223.xxx.222 dev enp4s0f1 proto static metric 101
default via 108.223.xxx.222 dev enp4s0f3 proto static metric 102
108.223.xxx.217 dev enp4s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 108.223.xxx.217 metric 100
108.223.xxx.217 dev enp4s0f3 proto kernel scope link src 108.223.xxx.217 metric 101
108.223.xxx.218 dev enp4s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 108.223.xxx.218 metric 100
108.223.xxx.218 dev enp4s0f3 proto kernel scope link src 108.223.xxx.218 metric 101
108.223.xxx.219 dev enp4s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 108.223.xxx.219 metric 100
108.223.xxx.219 dev enp4s0f3 proto kernel scope link src 108.223.xxx.219 metric 101
108.223.xxx.220 dev enp4s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 108.223.xxx.220 metric 100
108.223.xxx.220 dev enp4s0f3 proto kernel scope link src 108.223.xxx.220 metric 101
108.223.xxx.221 dev enp4s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 108.223.xxx.221 metric 100
108.223.xxx.221 dev enp4s0f3 proto kernel scope link src 108.223.xxx.221 metric 101
108.223.xxx.222 dev enp4s0f1 proto static scope link metric 100
108.223.xxx.222 dev enp4s0f3 proto static scope link metric 101
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.71 metric 100
192.168.1.71 dev enp4s0f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.71 metric 100
```

Errors from maillog

```
Dec 16 18:14:53 localhost sendmail[77855]: vBGNErI1077873: to=myemail@gmail.com, ctladdr=cdata (1000/1000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30014, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (vBGNErDq077874 Message accepted for delivery)
Dec 16 18:24:12 localhost sendmail[77855]: vBGGdu99077513: to=<myemail@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<myuser@mydomain.us> (1000/1000), delay=06:44:16, xdelay=00:10:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=750469, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [108.177.15.26], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Dec 16 18:24:12 localhost sendmail[77855]: vBGGAGt4077433: to=<myemail@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<myuser@mydomain.us> (1000/1000), delay=07:13:56, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=840469, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Dec 16 18:24:12 localhost sendmail[77855]: vBGFweLX077340: to=<myemail@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<myuser@mydomain.us> (1000/1000), delay=07:25:32, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=930469, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

Output of `netstat -tuplen | grep 25` to check that port 25 is open

```
$ sudo netstat -tuplen | grep 25
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          93443      10849/sendmail: acc
```

**EDIT:
The answer that this is marked as a duplicate of talks about relaying a gmail email. I don't think that's what I'm asking for.** I'm trying to originate an email from my server, on my domain and ip address, and send that to a remote email server. I read that answer and have tried to glean some insight, but I don't think that it's related. If it is, please explain how it's related.

EDIT AFTER ACCEPTING ANSWER:
The answer at [CentOS 6.2 sendmail: how to control the ip number used when relaying mail to mx.google.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/398658/centos-6-2-sendmail-how-to-control-the-ip-number-used-when-relaying-mail-to-mx) actually is the right answer, but I would have never recognized it as such because I didn't think that I was relaying an email. Thank you to everyone for helping me get it done.

Comment: Can you explain how that solves the problem? I've opened the file sendmail.mc and can't find any line regarding `CLIENT_OPTIONS(Family=...` Does it matter where I put it? Would I simply replace the `Address=x.x.x.66` with `Address=108.223.xxx.218`?

Comment: I changed the file adding the line referenced in the other post, ran `make all` in the sendmail folder and then ran `systemctl restart sendmail`. My outbound messages are still timing out, meaning they are not reaching the remote server. I don't think they've been rejected, I simply cannot connect regardless. Any idea where to check?

Comment: Remember that the lower route metric has higher priority. Are you sure you want the 192.168 address to be the preferred address for all outbound traffic?

Comment: I'm actually sure that I don't want that. Ideally outbound traffic could be routed based on the application making the requested action. I'll try to research that in the morning.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317151/change-default-gateway-for-specific-program

Comment: Do you have two Internet connections to the server?

Comment: There are 4 adapters, but at this moment I only have one ethernet plugged in.

Comment: There is so much "nope" in this I'm not even sure where to begin.  First, do you have good DNS resolution, i.e. it properly resolves names both inside and outside your network?  Second, have you checked your routing tables?  Third, your firewall rules are set correctly?  Fourth, you do realize that forcibly binding the SMTP service to a specific address isn't always going to be a good solution?

Comment: Hi Avery, this is old and already resolved. To answer your questions Yes,Yes,Yes, No. Thanks for the incredible amount of help you've given to so many on serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://www.unix-ninja.com/p/Changing_the_Source_IP_Address_in_Sendmail and make sure to absolutely follow the format, you need a back apostrophe before `Family` (it does not appear in your comment so maybe you forgot it?) . From experience it helps it you put `dnl` at end of statement so try something like that:

```
CLIENT_OPTIONS(`Family=inet, Address=203.0.113.2')dnl
```

just replacing the IP by one attached to your server (and make sure that there is no firewall cutting out outgoing connection from this IP).

Then:

1. `make` in the appropriate directory, like `/etc/mail`
2. restart sendmail

After make you can visually examine the .cf file you should see your IP in it, showing that the `CLIENT_OPTIONS` was properly taken into account.

As of where to put it, it could be relevant indeed, your files may be already documented, otherwise you would need to show more of your current `.mc` files.